# I would like to send data to two partitions with python and kafka, but I have this error: AssertionError: Unrecognized partition

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I'm using twitter for extract data with python and kafka and I would like to create two partitions in my topic, so this is my code in my producer file:

```
for tweet in hashtag_tweets:
    data = {}
    data["content"] = tweet._json["full_text"]
    data["retweets"] = tweet._json["retweet_count"]
    data["favorites"] = tweet._json["favorite_count"]
    if (aux % 2 == 0):
      producer.send('topic_test2', value=data, partition=0)
    else:
      producer.send('topic_test2', value=data, partition=1)  
    aux  += 1
```

And this is my docker-compose-expose.yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:3.4.6
    ports:
     - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
     - "9092:9092"
    expose:
     - "9093"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:9093,OUTSIDE://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://0.0.0.0:9093,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "topic_test:2:1"
    volumes:
     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

But when I run mi producer file, I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mariajesuscanoles/Desktop/lab_distribuidos/lab_productor.py", line 52, in <module>
    producer.send('topic_test2', value=data, partition=1)  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kafka/producer/kafka.py", line 587, in send
    partition = self._partition(topic, partition, key, value,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kafka/producer/kafka.py", line 720, in _partition
    assert partition in self._metadata.partitions_for_topic(topic), 'Unrecognized partition'
AssertionError: Unrecognized partition
```

Comment: Are you sure the topic actually was created with 2 partitions? The producer wont create more if they dont exist, as the error suggests

Comment: @OneCricketeer I did run his docker-compose file I do see two partitions getting created.

Answer (score 0):

Partition by key might make more sense here.
You can use your same odd/even logic, but use it to set the key.

https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/apache-kafka/partitions/

 https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/blob/4d598055dab7da99e41bfcceffa8462b32931cdd/kafka/producer/kafka.py#L555

And moreover this was normal error but not a bug.

 https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/issues/1537

Comment: Setting `key=aux` might not guarantee an even distribution of messages.